# Component id generation logic when using binding attribute in JSF?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have below code in UI

```
   <h:selectOneMenu id="state_radio"
        binding="#{createBean.selectedSpecState}"
        value="#{createBean.specVO.specState}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{createBean.states}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

As you can check above code i already gave the id for `SelectOneMenu` component as well as this component is bind with a bean variable but goind to another page and coming back to this page its giving below exception

> 17:00:40,401 SEVERE
>   [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application]
>   (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2) Error Rendering
>   View[/pages/somePage.xhtml]: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Component ID contentform:j_idt141:formForCreateLinkSpecs:j_idt172 has
>   already been found in the view.

and below is the generated output or source code for the component

> +id: state_radio
>                                type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectOneMenu@5a4427a3
>                                 +id: j_idt172  <===============
>                                  type: javax.faces.component.UISelectItems@76fa848e
>                                 +id: j_idt172  <===============
>                                  type: javax.faces.component.UISelectItems@3f6e615c
>                                 +id: j_idt172  <===============
>                                  type: javax.faces.component.UISelectItems@450b624e
>                                 +id: j_idt172  <===============
>                                  type: javax.faces.component.UISelectItems@60e00111
>                                 +id: j_idt172  <===============
>                                  type: javax.faces.component.UISelectItems@213b6823
>                                 +id: j_idt172  <===============
>                                  type: javax.faces.compon

Now if i remove the `binding`  its not throwing any id exception .

Now reason behind to use `binding` is that my page components not able to persist the value entered by user when going from this page to other page and coming back to same page.Bean is `session` managed bean.

**Update about Design:-**

I have a page A.xhtml where i included another page like this

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="createPanel">
    <rich:panel
    rendered="#{bean.isCreatePanel()}">
    <ui:insert name="createLinkTemplate">
    <ui:include src="../pages/somePage.xhtml" />
    </ui:insert>
    </rich:panel>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

Now  `A.xhtml` page also hold `somePage.xhtml` now from this page have logic to go another page and come back .

and i used below code to Navigate from one page to other page simple return pagename  with `faces-redirect=true`

```
public String navigateBack(){ 
return "pageName?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

Comment: To persist the value you only need value binding. You don't need to bind the component.

Comment: @JasperdeVries Agree but in my case its not persist thats why i used binding